# Iterating files in contents pane or in .mapx in ModelBuilder

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, iterator

**I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.6.1.**

I have consolidated a map and was able to shorten the name of the files within the resulting consolidate map folders. Consolidate Map tool also creates a map.mapx file with all the layers within it. I love this feature!

[image: Consolidating]

I am able to successfully truncate names in the resulting geodatabases and folders using calculate field but the layers in the map.mapx are still their original long names.

[image: Model where iterating through files and truncating names is successful]

So I try to truncate every layer in a .mapx. When I apply the same method but have a map.mapx file as the input, the model says it is successful, however, the names are still the same when I "add + import" the map.mapx. It still has the long names and not the sorter names.

[image]

I imagine that another way would be to iterate through the contents after I have "add + import" the map.mapx. I have not figured out yet how to iterate through the files in my contents likely because I am not sure if contents is even able to be an input for iterators.

I have just started working with iterators and have not found clarification in the help files when it applies to contents or map.mapx.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade your version of ArcPro to at least 2.7 then you will have access to a new iterator called [Iterate Layers](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.7/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-layers.htm). This allows you to step over layers in a map in a map document (aprx). I've personally never tested it against a `mapx` format.